# Facial Recognition

Tags: ipad, ios

Unless I was mistaken, this morning my iPad (purchased July - not Pro) popped up a tip about Facial Recognition unlocking. Unfortunately it disappeared before it sunk in.

I can no longer find any reference. Is it possible to unlock an iPad iOS12.1 with Facial Recognition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple only the iPad-Pro models have Facial Recognition at this time.

[image]

Comment: The non pro models don’t have the hardware for faceid. Also that is an opinion answers aware meant to be factual.